# Perl: Convert (high) decimal NCR to UTF-8

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8, decimal, ncr

I have this string (Decimal NCRs): `&#26085;&#26412;&#12398;&#37756;&#28792;&#12392;&#12399;`

It represents the Japanese text `日本の鍼灸とは`.

But I need (UTF-8): `%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E9%8D%BC%E7%81%B8%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF`

For the first character: `&#26085;` ⇒ `日` ⇒ `%E6%97%A5`

This site does it, but how do I get this in Perl? (If possible in a single regex like `s/\&\#([0-9]+);/uc('%'.unpack("H2", pack("c", $1)))/eg;`.)

http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php

Also I need to convert it back again from UTF-8 to Decimal NCRs

I've been breaking my head over this one for half a day now, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More tests => 2;
use Encode qw{ encode decode };

my $in = '&#26085;&#26412;&#12398;&#37756;&#28792;&#12392;&#12399;'; # 日本の鍼灸とは
my $out = '%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E9%8D%BC%E7%81%B8%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF';

(my $utf = $in) =~ s/&#(.*?);/chr $1/ge;

my $r = join q(), map { sprintf '%%%2X', ord } split //, encode('utf8', $utf);
is($r, $out);

(my $s = $r) =~ s/%(..)/chr hex $1/ge;
$s = decode('utf8', $s);
$s = join q(), map '&#' . ord . ';', split //, $s;
is($s, $in);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick responce, but I can't test your POC (i get errors in all the character-settings for the file I can think of), could you rewrite it with input ($in) `&#26085;&#26412;&#12398;&#37756;&#28792;&#12392;&#12399;`

Comment: @Eesger, Is your input `&#26085;&#26412;&#12398;&#37756;&#28792;&#12392;&#12399;` or `日本の鍼灸とは`?

Comment: @ikegami: It was the latter, now it's the former.

Comment: @choroba Great! almost there, $r is the conversion for getting $in to the result $out!

the second part converts to the characters (and validates), but I need the original value you edited (`&#26085;` etc.), can you do another update?

Answer (score 3):

What you call "UTF-8" is actually URL-encoding.

---

HTML entities (`&#26085;`) ⇒ text (`日`) ⇒ URI component (`%E6%97%A5`):

```
use HTML::Entities qw( decode_entities );
use URI::Escape    qw( uri_escape_utf8 );

my $text = decode_entities($html);
my $uri_component = uri_escape_utf8($text);
```

---

URI component (`%E6%97%A5`) ⇒ text (`日`) ⇒ HTML entities (`&#x65E5;`):

```
use Encode         qw( decode_utf8 );
use HTML::Entities qw( encode_entities );
use URI::Escape    qw( uri_unescape );

my $text = decode_utf8(uri_unescape($uri_component));
my $html = encode_entities($text);
```

Comment: with:
 <code>
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use HTML::Entities qw( encode_entities );
    use URI::Escape    qw( uri_escape_utf8 );
    my $html = '&#26085;';
    my $text = decode_entities($html);
    my $uri_component = uri_escape_utf8($text);
    print $uri_component."\n";
</code>

I get `panic: utf16_to_utf8: odd bytelen 53 at jp.pl line 12.`

Comment: I think that's because your Perl source file is badly encoded using UTF-16. Note that `use HTML::Entities qw( encode_entities );` should be  `use HTML::Entities qw( decode_entities );`.

Comment: You are right (UTF-16), your first parts is very good, your second parts results to `&#x65E5;&#x672C;&#x306E;&#x937C;&#x7078;&#x3068;&#x306F;` and not to `&#26085;&#26412;&#12398;&#37756;&#28792;&#12392;&#12399;`